# Synchronous Jquery ajax request not updating the elements

Tags: jquery, html, post

I want to iterate through the rows in my table and make an ajax request for every row that has the class "warning". That's working so far.

```
rows.each(function (i) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/Update/' + $(this).attr('rel'),
        success: function(c) {
            $('.table > tbody > tr.r[rel="' + c.Id +'"]').removeClass('warning').addClass('error');
        },
        dataType: "json",
        async:false
    });
});​
```

The removal of the class warning and the addition of class error will just display when the main function ends. Is there a way to update the page content in the `.each` loop in the moment I set the class? I also want to update a progress bar but it just jumps to 100% when the function is finished and not like 20% for each row.

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do. Maybe you need another .each function within the AJAX callback?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for another account. The other one I used at work because I didn't have my account details there.

I made a quick example on jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/m94Ay/3/

```
$('#Save').click(function () {
    var persons = $('.table > tbody.persons > tr.warning');
    if (persons.length == 0) {
        alert("Choose some persons please.");
        return;
    }
    var step = 100 / persons.length;
    var i;
    persons.each(function (i) {
        $(this).removeClass('warning').addClass('error');
        sleep(1000);
    });
});
```

Check three or four persons in the table and press save. Instead of removing and adding the classes every second it seems all are set together after 4 seconds.

I just simulated the ajax post with the sleep because the effect remains the same.